Multiprocessing Pool: return the minimum element
I want to run a task with a multiprocessing.Pool and return only the minimum element, without taking the memory to store every output.
My code so far:
with Pool() as pool:
  programs = pool.map(task, groups)
  shortest, l = min(programs, key = lambda a: len(a[0]))

This works, however this would occupy a lot of memory for the result of pool.map(). groups is a set, which can be really big, and the results would take up very much memory.
I would like some kind of approach like this:
with Pool() as pool:
  shortest, l = pool.execute_and_return_min(task, groups, key = lambda a: len(a[0]))

(which would internally compare the results and return the smallest element)
or:
with Pool() as pool:
  shortest = l = None
  for program, k in pool.apply_and_return_as_generator(task, groups):
    if shortest is None or len(program) < len(shortest):
      shortest = program
      l = k

(which would work like the normal pool but return values from the generator as soon as they are computed)
I couldn't find any method of the pool to achieve something like this. Since I only want the minimum element, I do not care about the order of execution.
Maybe I was not careful enough when searching.
Any help would be appreciated. Preferred is a solution with Pool(), but if you have an idea how to implement this using pther technique - please go ahead as well.
Thanks in advance!

Why don't you use the lazy iterator imap? Doesn't that do exactly what you want?

I must've been totally blind, this indeed seems to solve the issue.

There's also apply_async, you can use the callback to keep track of your minimum, but it would only speed things up in cases where you can know you no longer need to keep looking for more results.

imap_unordered is a better option as imap holds more return data as it has to track order. Even then, the pool may be pulling in data in the background. Its probably fine, but if you still have problems, you may have to do things more manually.

I went with imap_unordered in the end. Thanks

If you're interested to help out the community, you could write down your end conclusion in an informative answer, and accept your own answer. It helps curators and contributors figure out this question has been answered, and future readers find what they look for in code and explained :)

After reading the comments, I have found an optimal solution for me.
As @Robin De Schepper pointed out, there is the imap method, which is a lazy version of the map method.
Even better for me was the imap_unordered, which I went with at the end.
The upside of a lazy generator is that it doesn't have to process all items for the results to be available. Further, the unordered variant is even better, because it returns values as soon as they are ready. Since I do not need to preserve the order, this was the optimal method to use.
Final solution:
with Pool() as pool:
  shortest = l = None
  for program, k in pool.imap_unordered(task, groups):
    if shortest is None or len(program) < len(shortest):
      shortest = program
      l = k

